# Disabling li elements asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-lists

I programatically create `li` elements, however I need some of them disabled, so far I have:

```
HtmlGenericControl htmlLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
htmlLi.InnerText = row["name"].ToString();
tab_content.FindControl("tab_content_" + row["stars"].ToString()).Controls.Add(htmlLi);
```

Is it possible to disable them? If not, is their any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `<li>` element can't be disabled, as there's no input to prevent.
You can however hide the elements you don't want to be displayed.
You can either hide them from the code-behind:

```
htmlLi.Visible = false;
```

or you can add some styling to it so that it is put into the DOM, but made invisible by the CSS (so that you can make it visible again with javascript, should you want to):

```
htmlLi.Attributes.Add("style", "display: none");
```

or

```
htmlLi.Attributes.Add("class", "SomeInvisibleCssClass");
```